Compilation Errors with AWS S3 Ballerina Client: HttpServiceConfig and Union Type Inference Issues
I'm working on a Ballerina project that interacts with AWS S3 using the ballerinax/aws.s3 module. I have all my versions up to date, including Ballerina and all dependencies. However, I'm running into compilation errors that don't seem directly related to my use of the S3 module.
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/aws.s3;

configurable string accessKeyId = ?;
configurable string secretAccessKey = ?;
configurable string region = ?;
configurable string bucketName = ?;

s3:ConnectionConfig amazonS3Config = {
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region: region
};

s3:Client amazonS3Client = check new (amazonS3Config);

public function main() {
    error? createObjectResponse = amazonS3Client->createObject(bucketName, "test.txt", "Sample content");
    if (createObjectResponse is error) {
        log:printError("Error: " + createObjectResponse.toString());
    } else {
        log:printInfo("Object created successfully");
    }
}

However, when I compile the code, I get these errors:
ERROR [ballerina/http/2.6.2::http_annotation.bal:(60:19,60:36)] annotation declaration requires a subtype of 'true', 'map<value:Cloneable>' or 'map<value:Cloneable>[]', but found 'ballerina/http:2.6.2:HttpServiceConfig'
ERROR [ballerina/http/2.6.2::http_request_context.bal:(88:17,88:41)] invalid return type: members of a dependently-typed union type with an inferred typedesc parameter should have disjoint basic types
error: compilation contains errors


Ensured that both Ballerina and all dependencies are up to date

Ran bal clean and bal build to do a clean build

Verified that the AWS S3 module is compatible with my Ballerina distribution.

Isolated the S3 functionality by removing unnecessary imports, but the errors persist.


Questions
1. Why am I getting HTTP-related errors when my code is only using the AWS S3 module?
2. Is there a known conflict between the aws.s3 and http modules, or could this be a version compatibility issue?
3. How can I resolve these HttpServiceConfig and union type errors?

This could happen if your Ballerina version changes between builds. There can be dependencies that are compatible with the earlier version but not with the new one.  Can you try deleting the Dependencies.toml file in the project directory and running bal build again?
